# Ionic 2 dissmiss page slide down animation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a page which I call it with nav.push. Once I am there, I have an [x] to close it, and i use this.view.dismiss(), but since its not a modal, it closes the page with sliding right ( same as that nav.pop animation works ).

Is there a way to make a custom animation for this dissmiss, to slide-down.

I've used the animations for nav.push, like this one

```
this.nav.push(Page2, {}, { animate: true, direction: 'back' })
```

But there is no animation for slide down, or anything :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Native Page Transitions Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions/)

Using this plugin you've got full control over the animation.

Comment: This plugin is not optimal for me. Issue is that when i call with this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options); this.navCtrl.push(page); it makes the telerik transition, but after it the page still slides to the right (default ionic pop animation) so its very messy and not optimal. I just want to have the classic view.dismiss() modal animation with clear slide down page animation :/

Comment: ok, somehow I manage to tweak this out, by calling these lines of code: 

this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options);

this.nav.pop({animate:false});

this.nav.pop(page);

Comment: So popping twice ? Why you add the page in the argument ? Or do you use popTo() ? If you feel my answer was useful to you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help. The thing is that I can't put the code in ionViewWillLeave, because i have another slide to left animation once you click the back icon in the top. So i needed a function that will just pop the current page, with that custom animation. But, yes  after adjusting some settings in native page transition plugin, It all works good , in Ios at least.

Comment: Please note the options 'iosdelay' and 'androiddelay'